# How can I add a line break before a set of values going into a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, awk

I've got a set of data piping into a bash script.  Here's an example of what that data looks like:

```
"foo1": "Miscellaneous text",
    "foo2": "More text",
    "foo3": "blah blah blah",
      "foo4": 1635.0,
      "foo5": 0.0,
"foo1": "Miscellaneous text that is different",
    "foo2": "More text1231231",
    "foo3": "blah blah blah234234",
      "foo4": 1633425.0,
      "foo5": 0.0,
"foo1": "Miscellaneous text abc123",
    "foo2": "More text122121",
    "foo3": "blah blah blah414124",
      "foo4": 163235.0,
      "foo5": 1.0,
"foo1": "More Miscellaneous text",
    "foo2": "asdfasdfaMore text",
    "foo3": "blah blahadsfasdf blah",
      "foo4": 1635232.0,
      "foo5": 0.0,
```

I want to add a line break character (\n) to precede "foo1".  In other words, change the data to read:

```
    \n"foo1": "Miscellaneous text",
        "foo2": "More text",
        "foo3": "blah blah blah",
          "foo4": 1635.0,
          "foo5": 0.0,
    \n"foo1": "Miscellaneous text that is different",
        "foo2": "More text1231231",
        "foo3": "blah blah blah234234",
          "foo4": 1633425.0,
          "foo5": 0.0,
    \n"foo1": "Miscellaneous text abc123",
        "foo2": "More text122121",
        "foo3": "blah blah blah414124",
          "foo4": 163235.0,
          "foo5": 1.0,
    \n"foo1": "More Miscellaneous text",
        "foo2": "asdfasdfaMore text",
        "foo3": "blah blahadsfasdf blah",
          "foo4": 1635232.0,
          "foo5": 0.0,
```

I thought it would be possible to do with sed/awk but I'm not so sure as the values for foo1 can/will change.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to add a line break at the beginning of every line that doesn't start with a space/tab?

Comment: @scai I suppose that would work but I was originally wanting to add a line break at the beginning of every line that begins with `"foo1":`

Comment: I thought the "foo1": can/will change? If not, it is really easy. See my answer.

Comment: foo1 stays the same. The value for foo1 is what changes.  For example, it could be "Miscellaneous text".  It could later be "Miscellaneous text that is different"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a '\n' for every line starting with "foo":

```
sed 's/^"foo1":/\n&/'
```

Comment: There's a typo: "foo" should be "foo1". The best way to prevent such typos: `sed 's/^"foo1":/\n&/'`

Answer (score 2):

`awk` solutions:

```
$ awk '{ sub(/^"foo1"/, "\\n&") }; 1'
$ awk '{ if (/^"foo1"/) { print "\\n" $0 } else { print $0 } }'
```

Since you said:

> I want to add a line break character (\n) to precede "foo1"

So I escaped the backslash to insert a `\n` character instead of a new line.